# How do I train invocations with manual skill allocation?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I'm currently playing a character worshiping [Sif Muna](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Sif_Muna), and need [invocations](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Invocations) to help boost my [channel energy](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Channel_energy) ability. However, when I go to the skill menu invocations is not an available option to select for training. I'm using manual skill allocation, playing Stone Soup v. 0.12.1, and have the ability to use channel energy. How can I train invocations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **should** be able to train invocations as soon as you have an ability to invoke (like channel energy). I've uninstalled crawl (I really needed my time!) so I can't check it right now. But if you're sure you had the channel energy ability, you could have found a bug, or lost the ability (from piety drop) without noticing it.

Comment: You are completely correct that I should have been able to, and since in the version I have currently, I can, I'm accepting "a bug" as the correct answer.